# Time difference between two time stamps

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains the following datetime stamps of the class `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`:

```
1899-12-30 08:00:37
1899-12-30 08:03:54
1899-12-30 08:05:31
1899-12-30 08:12:55
```

I need to calculate the difference (in minutes) between subsequent rows. The result for the first row should be (i.e. 08:03:54-08:00:37):

```
1899-12-30 08:00:37      3.28
```

I use this code to calculate the difference, but the outputs do not coincide with manual calculations.

```
c_time <- df$datetime
intervals = c(difftime(ymd_hms(c_time[2:length(c_time)]),
                                ymd_hms(c_time[1:(length(c_time)-1)]),
                                units="mins"),0)
```

Comment: you can try `difftime(df[,1],lag(df[,1]))`, assuming your `POSIXct` column is the first one.

Comment: @mtoto: I tried `intervals = difftime(ymd_hms(c_time),
                                lag(ymd_hms(c_time)),
                                units="mins")`, but then the error says that replacement has more rows than original data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `lubridate` and `dplyr`. It is one option among others.

```r
df <- data.frame(dtime = c(
"1899-12-30 08:00:37",
"1899-12-30 08:03:54",
"1899-12-30 08:05:31",
"1899-12-30 08:12:55"))

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate(dtime = ymd_hms(dtime), 
         diff = lead(dtime) - dtime)
#>                 dtime          diff
#> 1 1899-12-30 08:00:37 3.283333 mins
#> 2 1899-12-30 08:03:54 1.616667 mins
#> 3 1899-12-30 08:05:31 7.400000 mins
#> 4 1899-12-30 08:12:55       NA mins
```